Kitten Doesn’t Use Liter Box Properly
My almost 6 month old, female kitten doesn’t know how to use the liter box properly. She was a rescue and didn’t have a mom. She goes into the liter box, digs a hole , but poops on the mound. So when she tries to bury it , the poop rolls down the mound and she steps  in it , and tracks it around.  Help, is there any hope that she will figure this out?  How can I teach her what to do?

This question is similar to: Kitten always gets dirty from stool. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
